# DataType vs ContentType in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

What is the significance of DataType and ContentType in jquery ajax ?
What is the purpose of both in client side request and  Server side response ?

Comment: Is the content-type and data-type purpose differs between jQuery usage and REST API usage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**dataType:**

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

**contentType:**

> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). The W3C
>   XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always
>   UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change
>   the encoding.

Comment: Is the content-type and data-type purpose differs between jQuery usage and REST API usage?

Answer (score 2):

contentType is used to determine how the payload has to be sent to the server as request parameters or as request body.

dataType is used to tell jQuery what is the return type of the request - to determine how to process the response text before it is sent the the handler methods